# a [CFString release] cause crash when releasing NSKeyedUnarchiver

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch

```
+(id)decodeObjectForKey:(NSString *)key fromFile:(NSString *)fileName
{
    NSData* data = [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:[self dataFilePath:fileName]];
    NSKeyedUnarchiver* unarchiver = [[NSKeyedUnarchiver alloc] initForReadingWithData:data];
    id object = [unarchiver decodeObjectForKey:key];
    [unarchiver finishDecoding];

    [data release];
#warning  some trouble here!!
    [unarchiver release];   
    return object;
}
```

that's a function in my app_delegate,but when I call it, the program crashes and give such note:

```
-[CFString release]: message sent to deallocated instance 0x4e63a60
```

I don't know where did I send a release to CFString?

PS: dataFilePath function:

```
+(NSString*)dataFilePath:(NSString*) appdix
{
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES); 
    NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0]; 
    return [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:appdix];
}
```

Comment: If you build with ARC you can avoid worrying about most of these issues

Answer (score 0, accepted):

decodeObjectForKey returns an autoreleased object. I think you should retain this object and release it later after your use..

In **your** decodeObjectForKey Function..No change here..

```
//no change here..
id object = [unarchiver decodeObjectForKey:key];
...
return object;
```

Now when you use **your** decodeObjectKey function retain the value it returns

```
id returnedObject = [[yourAppDelegate decodeObjectForKey:@"yourKey" fromFile:@"yourFile"]retain];
//do whatever you need with this variable..
......
...
//after your usage..
[returnedObject release];
```

Hope this will help..

Comment: what is [returnObject release]? should it be return [object autorelease]?

Comment: nope..we can directly release this since we own it now (by retaining) and we no longer need this variable.. Also note returnObject is a variable name I have given..I dont think you have read my answer correctly..Ok I will edit the variable name..

Comment: I got it, sorry for my misunderstanding.